# Signing in of registered users on ejabberd server from Conversations client app is not working

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have an ejabberd server running on Amazon EC2. I added users from the web admin console and then I tried to log in from Conversations app using the JID as my-name@ec2-3-142-252-179.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com and using the password assigned during registration. But it keeps on saying "server not found". Please tell me where I am doing wrong. Thank you.

[Here is the screenshot of web admin console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fADHC.png)

[Sign in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb51h.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I never used Amazon EC2, so I will only give you some wild ideas. Also, I don't have Conversations in English, so my translation may not be exactly like what you see:

A) In that same window, click in ... -> Preferences -> Experts Configuration -> Extended connection configuration: enable that option. Now you get another two fields, so you can tell there Conversations exacly the host (or the IP address) and port of ejabberd. Maybe adding it here helps?

B) When you attempt the connection in Conversations, do you get anything relevant in ejabberd.log or similar? I guess no

C) You can access ejabberd webadmin from your PC, but you can't from your Android phone. Just for curiosity, can you access the ejabberd webadmin from your mobile?

D) You can install some desktop Jabber client, like Gajim, Psi,... in your PC. Do those eclients connect to ejabberd, or faiol like Conversations?